# Hyper-v back-up

Tags: backup, hyper-v, symantec, backupexec

We are trying to decide a good backup strategy for our new Hyper-V setup.

We have 3 VMs on Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V host. We installed Symantec BackupExec 2010 on the host and have the Hyper-V Agent installed.

We would like to perform a full backup at night to tape, and an incremental twice a day to a daily tape.

Our environment needs constant protection for our database (Microsoft Access).

Any thoughts? Should I be looking at different software?

Comment: Possibly Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/240406/hyper-v-and-backup-exec-2010 - http://serverfault.com/questions/60452/backing-up-hyper-v-server - http://serverfault.com/questions/110675/backup-strategy-for-windows-server-2008-r2-and-hyper-v

Answer (score 9):

If you need constant protection for your database, you shouldn't be using Access. Period.  At very least move up to Sql Server Express Edition (which is free!), and what you really want is an edition that supports a feature like log shipping or similar to keep a mirror up-to-date with something like a 15 minute lag.

Comment: I know this might sound harsh but its true. Storing valuable data in access is a lot like storing rare bird eggs inside someone else's boots and not telling them; sooner or later your data's gonna get scrambled.

Comment: +1: Constant protection and Access are mutually exclusive!

Comment: +1 to Robert for the witty anecdote! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you stick with a VSS-compliant database ap for Hyper-V. ActiveImage Protector from Rectiphy does really fast live backups - no interuptions. Plus, when needed, you can restore just one of the VMs instead of having to restore the while image (like other backup tools.) Good price too.

Answer (score 0):

I am happily backing up a Windows 2008 Server that serves as a VMware host to four VMs with Windows Home Server, believe it or not.  It's been running great for eighteen months, and the VM clients and host itself is backed up nightly.  The same should work for your Hyper-V setup.